# Setting MaxWidth at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

This is a .Net 4.5 WPF question.
I am trying to set the MaxWidth of a FrameworkElement defined in XAML (specifically, an Expander) programmatically, but I've tried

- myFrameworkElement.MaxWidth = value
- myFrameworkElement.SetValue(MaxWidthProperty,value)
  -and-
- myFrameworkElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MaxWidth = value);

No joy. When I run it through the debugger, MaxWidth stubbornly remains at the value specified at compile-time in the XAML. Is it even possible to set MaxWidth and MaxHeight at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you databind the maxwidth to a property?

Comment: Or should you set `ActualWidth` instead?

Comment: When are you setting it, after the Layout is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the MaxWidth of your control in double in code.
For example,
for Textbox names txtTest you can set its maxwidth as below.

```
txtTest.MaxWidth=300.0;
```

In case of Expander as well this mechanism works properly. can you show me your xaml how you have defined your expander